Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/asset/sound/beep.mp3"
I'm trying to use audioplayers plugin in flutter (Android), functionality is that once user scan the barcode, beep sound should play after that.
Here is my pubspec.yml code:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_overlay_loader: ^2.0.0
  provider: ^6.0.0
  collection: ^1.15.0
  permission_handler: ^8.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^1.1.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  barcode_scan2: ^4.3.0
  audioplayers: ^5.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: asset/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
        - asset: asset/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - asset/images/
    - asset/images/audit/
    - asset/images/inquiry/
    - asset/images/common_icon/
    - asset/images/bottomNavigation/
    - asset/images/floatingButton/
    - asset/json/user/
    - asset/sound/

My folder looks like this:

and I'm using it like this:
 void handleBarcodeScan() async {
    var result = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    print(result.rawContent);
    if (result.rawContent.isNotEmpty) {
      // Play beep sound
      AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
      await audioPlayer.play(AssetSource('asset/sound/beep.mp3'));
    }
    handleAddButtonPress(
      barcode: result.rawContent,
      inventoryDetails: widget.inventoryDetails,
    );
  }

I'm getting this error: Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/asset/sound/beep.mp3".

That package assumes the path is "assets/*".  So you can either rename your folder, or figure out how to get the right path into the AudioCache. You can see the code here: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/packages/audioplayers/lib/src/audio_cache.dart#L57

had to rename folder, Thanks :)

Please follow the correct path, configure in your pubspec.yaml
  assets:
     - assets/images/

place e.g an image file "myImage.png" and call in your code using the path:
static Widget myImage = Image.asset('assets/images/myImage.png');


I had the same issue.
First you dont need the extra 'assets' because AudioPlayer has by default a prefix called 'assets'
https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md
AssetSource: play an asset bundled with your app, by default within the assets directory. To customize the prefix, see https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md#audiocache
try this before initiating the AudioPlayer
AudioCache.instance = AudioCache(prefix: '');

So the result should look like this:
AudioCache.instance = AudioCache(prefix: '');
final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
await audioPlayer.play(AssetSource('sound/beep.mp3'));

